# @Autowired : No qualifying bean of type available SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations, autowired

I have an interface **com.myapp.org.UsageRateLimiter** defined in a library

```
public interface UsageRateLimiter {
  
  boolean tryAndConsume(String userId, String key, Long units);
}
```

I have a concrete class **SlidingWindowRateLimiter** :

```
@Component("slidingWindowRateLimiter")
public class SlidingWindowRateLimiter implements UsageRateLimiter {
  private final RateLimitingRedisProperties rateLimitingRedisProperties;

  public SlidingWindowRateLimiter(RateLimitingRedisProperties rateLimitingRedisProperties) {
    this.rateLimitingRedisProperties = rateLimitingRedisProperties;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean tryAndConsume(String userId, String key, Long units) {
    
    return true;
}
```

Another class **com.myapp.org.RateLimitDriver** had a reference to object of *UsageRateLimiter* type :

```
public class RateLimiterDriver {
  UsageRateLimiter rateLimiter;

  @Autowired
  RateLimiterDriver(UsageRateLimiter usageRateLimiter) {
    rateLimiter = usageRateLimiter;
  }

  public Decision getDecision(
      String userId, String key, BiFunction<String, String, Long> consumptionObject) {
    return rateLimiter.tryAndConsume(
            userId, key, consumptionObject.apply(userId, key))
        ? true
        : false;
  }
}
```

There are going to be other implementations of **UsageRateLimiter** as well with different **Component** names

Now in my controller class I need to instantiate **RateLimiterDriver** :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myApp/v1")
@Slf4j
public class MyappController implements MyappApi {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("slidingWindowRateLimiter")
  private RateLimiterDriver rateLimiterDriver;

  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<MyappResponse> createMyAppInstance(
      @RequestBody MyappPayload myAppPayload) {
    if (rateLimiterDriver.getDecision(userId, "create_my_app") == Decision.ALLOW) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
    }
  }
}
```

During deployment I am getting the below error:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.org.RateLimiterDriver' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="slidingWindowRateLimiter")}
```

**Update** : As I understand, the *Qualifier ("slidingWindowRateLimiter")* shouldn't be on the RateLimitDriver class but on the UsageLimiter class.

How can I pass on the correct UsageLimiter implementation from MyAppController using spring annotation? Sorry I'm new to spring boot, hence seeking help.

Comment: You have no `@Component` annotation on your `RateLimiterDriver`. Also you have qualifier `slidingWindowRateLimiter` on other class, not RateLimiterDriver, but SlidingWindowRateLimiter

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Are these classes all in appropriate packages being component scanned?

Comment: Are you sure `@Qualifier("slidingWindowRateLimiter")` should not be used in `RateLimiterDriver` class instead `MyAppController` class like you are doing ?

Comment: Thanks @timofeevle. How can I instantiate `RateLimiterDriver` bean with the right concrete implementation of `UsageRateLimiter` from the Controller? Sorry I'm new to Spring Boot, hence asking. I might be doing this completely wrong.

Comment: In your case it seems like that you wrote qualifier in wrong place. You can move this qualifier to `RateLimiterDriver` constructor, add Component annotation and it will work. But it`s not very good idea to use qualifiers, because IoC idea is lost, you have coupling with particular class. It's better way to define which class will be used in external config class, f.e. in java config

Comment: @timofeevle Can you please post an example on how to pass it during the runtime using config

Answer (score -1):

Finally I was able to come up with a solution using the fact that **Spring provides the capability to collect all Beans which are concrete implementations of an interface into a Map**

I modified my **RateLimiterDriver** class as:

```
@Component
public class RateLimiterDriver {
  @Value("${com.myapp.org.ratelimiter.type}")
  private String rateLimiterType;

  Map<String, UsageRateLimiter> rateLimiterTypeImplMap;

  @Autowired
  RateLimiterDriver(Map<String, UsageRateLimiter> rateLimiterTypeMap) {
    rateLimiterTypeImplMap = rateLimiterTypeMap;
  }

  public Decision getDecision(
      String userId, String key, BiFunction<String, String, Long> consumptionObject) {
    return rateLimiterTypeImplMap
            .get(rateLimiterType)
            .tryAndConsume(userId, key, consumptionObject.apply(userId, key))
        ? Decision.ALLOW
        : Decision.DROP;
  }
}
```

In my **MyAppController**, I am able to simply do

```
@Autowired RateLimiterDriver
```

and provide the bean name in the properties file:

```
com.myapp.org.ratelimiter.type=slidingWindowRateLimiter
```

Voila! Things working fine now. Thanks @timeofeevle for the suggestion.

Reference articles:

[Dynamic autowire in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dynamic-autowire)